# How do I get the latest timestamp inserted in the dynamodb table?

Tags: python, amazon-dynamodb

I want to get the recent record added to the table from above (partition key = variable_key)

I did research and found out you can do this with
Query(hash_key=..., ScanIndexForward=True, limit=1)
But I m not getting the result can someone please explain me how should I do it?

Comment: Welcome to [Stack Overflow.](https://stackoverflow.com/ "Stack Overflow") Please be aware this is not a code-writing or tutoring service. We can help solve specific, technical problems, not open-ended requests for code or advice. Please edit your question to show what you have tried so far, and what specific problem you need help with. See the [How To Ask a Good Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask "How To Ask a Good Question") page for details on how to best help us help you.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to add the code. 
I fixed my issue and posted the answer thanks for responding @itprorh66

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for those who are looking for answer, I solved this issue by storing timestamp of my last entry and then using scan and "LastEvaluatedKey".

Check the below code:
I stored my last entry with the timestamp, used scan and last evaluatedkey and then pandas df to sort out values.

```
response_variable=midstore.scan()
items_variable = r_variable['Items']
while 'LastEvaluatedKey' in r_variable:
    r_variable = midstore.scan(ExclusiveStartKey=r_variable['LastEvaluatedKey'])
    items_variable.extend(r_variable['Items'])
#print(r_variable)
last_df = pd.DataFrame(items_variable)
last_df["storage_key"]=pd.to_datetime(last_df["storage_key"]) ##Storage_key is the partition key from dynamodb table.

last_df=last_df.sort_values("storage_key")
last_element=last_df.iloc[-1]
#print(last_element["storage_key"])
LatestEntry = str(last_element['storage_key'])
#print(LatestEntry )
```